# Should the word while be capitalized in a title?

Tags: conjunctions, capitalization

This is the title of a session at a conference:

> Capturing Innovation while Maximizing Performance: Technological and Financing Choices That Shape Market Impact

Should while be capitalized or not?

Comment: Yes, capitalize it.

Comment: And don't capitalize *that*.

Comment: It would depend on the house style sheet of the journal in question.  You have bigger worries: what does it mean to "capture" innovation?

Answer (score 2):

There are various rules for capitalization.  Some suggest you capitalize all words except conjunctions, and prepositions shorter than 4-5 letters, unless they are the first or last words in the title.

[Rules for Capitalization in Titles of Articles](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalization-in-titles.html)

So in your title:

> Capturing Innovation While Maximizing Performance: Technological and Financing Choices That Shape Market Impact

As verbose points out, some guides say you should not capitalize "that", but it's really your decision.  I think it looks better capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

There is no complete standard  or rule about that however because the word is not short, you can capitalize it. The word like **of**, **and** etc which have few number of letters and they are based on preposition or conjuction are not capitalized.

For me it is better for it to be capitalized otherwise make entire title in uppercase.